# HSQLDB connection URL: user and pwd properties

Tags: hsqldb

Chapter 12 of the HSQLDB docs says: "The properties user and password are always required." but AFAICT does not specify the syntax for supplying them as part of the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example using the URL is below:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/enrollments;user=user500240;password=nothing
```

If you are using a java.util.Properties object with the  `DriverManager.getConnection (String url, Properties info)` call, then you should set the properties with the calls below before calling the getConnection method:

```
info.setProperty("user", "user500240");
info.setProperty("password", "nothing");
```

Update: Links to Javadoc and the Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/apidocs/org.hsqldb/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCConnection

http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_connection_url

Comment: So these are standard properties; thanks. I had peeked into DatabaseURL and that had confused me because it looks for "?user=" and "&password=", suggesting they were somehow special.

Comment: he syntax: '?user=user500240&password=nothing' can also be used at the end of the URL as an alternative form.

Comment: There's a link in the HSQLDB documentation referring to their javadocs. The use of `key-value-pairs` is explained for various connection types. http://hsqldb.org/doc/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/jdbcConnection.html